# Eliminate stray whitespace between textboxes on a report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, whitespace

I have 4 stacked textboxes in the body of an SSRS report and am getting a stray space / extra line between textboxes 3 & 4.

This is for an address block - name / title / email / website.  Can't put it in a single textbox with intervening vbcrlf tokens because the email and website are links.  I've tried formatting it to remove vertical spacing; also calculated the exact position by taking top + height to calculate the position.  And of course I've tried positioning it so there are exactly 0 pixels between the text boxes.  If I reverse the position of #3 & #4 the rendering looks the same so it isn't stray formatting characters in the data fields.

Comment: Why not put the info into table?

Comment: Have you tried giving the textboxes a visible border so that you can see where their boundaries are?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to wrap the stacked boxes in a rectangle.

I had this problem as well. It blew my mind until I started over on another part of the form. The new boxes worked perfectly until I moved them to the right of another set of text boxes which had some word wrap in them. I realized the wordwrapped boxes were directly related to the gaps I was seeing the set of textboxes to the right. I guess there's some kind of poor markup going on that tries to line things up horizontally and enclosing the set of textboxes in a rectangle protects them from it.

Answer (score 0):

good idea on putting the info into a table - jumping off that idea - I'm going to construct a dynamic string in my query and output the dynamic string into a textbox. thank you for the idea, I don't know why I didn't think to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler thing is to just check text alignment - the default is "default" which appears to be centered. Changing the text box to the right to "left" fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reduce padding property of the textbox.
2. Once dragging the textbox one closer to the other the tooltip shows convergence points between two textboxes - make tooltip show 0 points

it is best I could do to control the spacing